# How to understand Visual Studio App Center crash stacktraces

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, crash, visual-studio-app-center

Recently I set up Visual Studio App Center's crash logging on my UWP app which is published on the Microsoft Store.

I noticed that my app crashed a few times on App Center's dashboard, but I don't understand how those "stack traces" shown on the dashboard can be useful to me. They do not contain any line numbers and therefore I can't know where exactly the bug is in my app.

I also uploaded my app's symbols to Visual Studio App Center.

Here's a screenshot of the crash from Visual Studio App Center's dashboard:
[image]

I can understand that the exception was thrown in the `doLoginAsync` method, but that method is complex and I need more details about where the exception occurred.

How can I understand where exactly is the problem from Visual Studio App Center's crash stack traces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem by uploading my app's correct symbols to the App Center.

In my case the app was already on the Microsoft Store but I had only uploaded my locally-generated symbols. Those locally-generated symbols didn't match the version that got published on the store because before getting published symbols are generated again from Microsoft side.

To download the new symbols I had to go to the Microsoft Partner Center, then go to my app's page, and then to the `Manage Packages` section:

[image]

Then, from this section I could download my app's symbols and then upload them to App Center.

Most of the time App Center doesn't signal that crashes are unsymbolicated, so you have to remember to upload the new symbols every time you publish a new version of your app.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, you could customize the crash report by adding some attachments. This could help to make the report to be more readable. You could use the **Crashes.GetErrorAttachments** to add binary and text attachments to a crash report.

Like:

```
    Crashes.GetErrorAttachments = (ErrorReport report) =>
{
    // Your code goes here.
    return new ErrorAttachmentLog[]
    {
        ErrorAttachmentLog.AttachmentWithText("Hello world!", "hello.txt"),
        ErrorAttachmentLog.AttachmentWithBinary(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Fake image"), "fake_image.jpeg", "image/jpeg")
    };
};
```

More information could be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/sdk/crashes/uwp#add-attachments-to-a-crash-report

**Besides**, the app center team is providing support on their dashboard. You could directly raise a support ticket on App Center Site. Please check this: [Help and feedback](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/help#accessing-app-center-free-support)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I looked into this but I don't think this can solve my problem, which is to know where exactly the crash happened. Attachments can be useful in some contexts that need more user-specific data, but if no line numbers are shown in the stack traces then I don't understand how those logs can be useful. I opened a ticket on the website, if I come to a solution I will post there.

Comment: @Gabboxl Sure, once you've got a solution from the ticket, please consider sharing it here.